# dplyr full_join does not work as expected

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a toy example (where merge is from the base package and full from dplyr):

```
require(dplyr)
a = data.frame(Day=Sys.Date()+1:5,x=1:5)
b = data.frame(Day=Sys.Date()-1:5,x=3*(1:5))

x1 = b
x2 = b
for(i in 1:10){
   x1=full_join(x1,a,by="Day")
   x2 = merge(x2,a,by="Day",all=T)
}
```

x1 and x2 are different. I would expect x2 since "a" is appended to the end.
This is x2 (first 5 lines):

```
2015-05-14 15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

2015-05-15 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

2015-05-16 9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

2015-05-17 6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

But x1 from full_join is:

```
Day x.x x.y x.x x.y x.x x.y x.x x.y x.x x.y x

1 2015-05-18 3 NA 3 NA 3 NA 3 NA 3 NA NA

2 2015-05-17 6 NA 6 NA 6 NA 6 NA 6 NA NA

3 2015-05-16 9 NA 9 NA 9 NA 9 NA 9 NA NA
```

Is this a bug? Or is this expected? I would expect the output from merge (x2) as the logically correct.... I want x2 using dplyr full_join. Is there a way?

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't have an `i` to loop over. What 10 items are you trying to cycle through?

Comment: The i is not relevant. I just wanted to create a simple example that merges sequentially several data.frames. In this case I am merging the same data.frame "a" to the right of x1 (or x2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of the two methods are the same if you rename the column in the dataframe `a`:

```
require(dplyr)
a = data.frame(Day=Sys.Date()+1:5,y=1:5)
b = data.frame(Day=Sys.Date()-1:5,x=3*(1:5))

x1 = b
x2 = b
for(i in 1:10){
  x1=full_join(x1,a,by="Day")
  x2=merge(x2,a,by="Day",all=T)
}

# fix up the column names...
names(x1) <- sapply(1:ncol(x1), function(x) {paste0("V", x)})
names(x2) <- sapply(1:ncol(x2), function(x) {paste0("V", x)})

x1 %>% arrange(desc(V1))
x2 %>% arrange(desc(V1))
```

So here I have changed this line:

```
a = data.frame(Day=Sys.Date()+1:5,x=1:5)
```

to

```
a = data.frame(Day=Sys.Date()+1:5,y=1:5)
```

Why does this happen? When you run the code you have provided above you should actually get a warning message. On my version of R I get the following:

```
Warning messages:
1: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
2: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
3: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
4: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
5: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
6: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
7: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
8: In merge.data.frame(x2, a, by = "Day", all = T) :
  column names ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’, ‘x.x’, ‘x.y’ are duplicated in the result
```

So I think, that the reason why the results from `full_join` and `merge` don't match in this instance is because of the ambiguous columns in the two data frames you have provided. When you remove this ambiguity, then the results match as expected, so I do not think this is a bug.

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem. I agree, it looks like the issue are the col names. However it is a little strange that it is dependent on the col names. Indeed merge gives us warnings but still does the "correct" think...